# Accurately targeting <div> in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building an interactive quiz for users of my app. The questions are table based, and can be answered "yes," "no," or "maybe." If the user answers "no" or "maybe," I would to slide open an informational panel that lives beneath the table.

Here is the code for the table and info panel:

```
<div class="row quiz">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr class="active">
        <th colspan="3"><strong>1. Executive Support</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Yes</strong></th>
        <th><strong>No</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Don't Know</strong></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Do the executives prioritize—or express a desire to prioritize—initiatives based on patient and family needs?</td>
        <td class="radio-button">
          <div class="radio">
            <label>
              <input type="radio" class="no-toggle" name="toggle" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1">
            </label>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="radio-button">
          <div class="radio">
            <label>
              <input type="radio" class="toggle" name="toggle" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">
            </label>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="radio-button">
          <div class="radio">
            <label>
              <input type="radio" class="toggle" name="toggle" id="optionsRadios3" value="option3">
            </label>
          </div>    
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Do you have the support of your executive management group?</td>
        <td class="radio-button">
          <div class="radio">
            <label>
              <input type="radio" class="no-toggle" name="toggle2" id="optionsRadios2" value="option5">
            </label>
          </div>
        </td>            <td class="radio-button">
          <div class="radio">
            <label>
              <input type="radio" class="toggle" name="toggle2" id="optionsRadios2" value="option5">
            </label>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="radio-button">
          <div class="radio">
            <label>
              <input type="radio" class="toggle" name="toggle2" id="optionsRadios3" value="option6">
            </label>
          </div>    
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3"> Do you presently have commitment from key administrative and clinical champions to help overcome <br>the inevitable barriers to designing and delivering ideal care experiences?</td>
        <td class="radio-button">
          <div class="radio">
            <label>
              <input type="radio" class="no-toggle" name="toggle3" id="optionsRadios2" value="option5">
            </label>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="radio-button">
          <div class="radio">
            <label>
              <input type="radio" class="toggle" name="toggle3" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">
            </label>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="radio-button">
          <div class="radio">
            <label>
              <input type="radio" class="toggle" name="toggle3" id="optionsRadios3" value="option3">
            </label>
          </div>    
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div><!-- table-responsive-->
<div class="row notes_section clear">
    <div class="notes_wrap js-notes">
        <a href="#" class="active">Build More Executive Support in Your Organization</a>
        <div class="notes_main_wrap" style="display: block;">
            <div class="notes_item">
                    <p>If you're having difficulty obtaining support from your organization's leadership, it can help to demonstrate some of the real-world successes of other Working Groups. You can approach this in a variety of ways:</p>
                    <ol>
                        <li>Provide your leadership with  PFCC Step-by-Step: The Business Case [Document Forthcoming], which explains why PFCC Step-by-Step is the singular tool for care transformation.</li>
                        <li>Explain how front-line care givers that participate in PFCC Step-by-Step often experience an improved morale, as well as an  increased emotional connection with patients and families.</li>
                        <li>Explain that the principles of PFCC Step-by-Step have been endorsed by leading healthcare institutions worldwide. To further illustrate, <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sGlJDk6WOxM&amp;list=PLqj3nHFwDQMRB4F_P4303ixiD_sxOQ0Vt&amp;index=61" target="_blank">share this video</a> with your leadership. 
                    </li></ol>
            </div><!-- /notes_item -->
        </div><!-- notes_main_wrap -->
    </div><!--notes_wrap -->
</div><!--notes_section -->
```

And here is my jQuery:

```
$('document').ready(function() {

//Quiz Toggle Functionality
$('input:radio[class^="toggle"]').change(
function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.js-notes > a').addClass('active');
        $('.js-notes > a').next('.notes_main_wrap').slideDown();
        return false;
    }
});
$('input:radio[class^="no-toggle"]').change(
function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.js-notes > a').removeClass('active');
        $('.js-notes > a').next('.notes_main_wrap').slideUp();
        return false;
    }
});
});
```

However, my solution unfolds every instance of the .notes_main_wrap div on the page (there are four.) I only want to unfold the next instance, not all of them. What jQuery selector do I need to use to only target the next instance of a class on the page?

Comment: instead of $('.js-notes > a').next('.notes_main_wrap').slideDown(); try $('.js-notes > a').next('.notes_main_wrap:first').slideDown(); the :first condition will only get the first one.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique. And since your questions and answers are essentially disconnected, you probably want to use the index of the question when showing the related information. That or a custom data attribute.

Comment: @Valeklosse, thanks! Unforunately, your solution allows me to target the first instance of .notes_main_wrap on the page. Instead, I need the _next_ instance on the page, regardless of its order on the page.

Comment: try $(this).closest('table').next('.notes_main_wrap').slideDown();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the next element, you can first search upwards to the nearest '.table-responsive' parent and then get the next element : `$(this).closest('.table-responsive').next('div').find('.js-notes > a')`
Fortunately, you can combine the 2 functions into one and toggle the toggling so to speak with `toggleClass` and `slideToggle`:

```
$('input:radio.toggle, input:radio.no-toggle').change(
function(){
    if ($(this).val()) {
        var toggle = $(this).hasClass('toggle'); 

        $(this).closest('.table-responsive').next('div').find('.js-notes > a')
            .toggleClass('active', toggle)
            .next('.notes_main_wrap').slideToggle(toggle);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Example: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfxum1oq/)

NB: the original working in which only the *last* changed input determines if the comments are shown, is unchanged. If you'd want to check if any of the options are 'yes', an additional query would be needed.

NB2: the ids and toggle values were ..uhm.. not entirely accurate in the example html, neither are they in the copy/pasted example, so the checkboxes might influence one and other. However the jquery code itself should work as far as finding the next js notes etc. is concerned.

Comment: Yeah, no, the HTML in my example is all boilerplate from the Bootstrap docs. Answer worked wonderfully, though. Thank you!